# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ is a domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-domain

> We consider the ideal $I=(x-y-1,x^2+y^2-2x)$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. We have to show if $I$ is a prime ideal in both ring. In $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$

I think is not a prime ideal, since: $$2x(x-y-1)-(x^2+y^2-2x)=x^2-y^2-2xy=x^2+y^2-2xy-2y^2=(x-y)^2-2y^2=(x-y-\sqrt{2}y)((x-y+\sqrt{2}y)) \in I$$ but neither $x-y-\sqrt{2}y$ or $x-y+\sqrt{2}y$ is in $I$, it is right? To prove that $I$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, I think to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ is a domain, but I don't see the right way.

Comment: **Hint:** We have $\Bbb Q[x,y]/I\cong\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-(x-1)^2-2x)$.

Comment: Perfect, I understand, thank you!

Comment: As Berci said, the third isomorphism theorem is your friend here. Divide out by one generator at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $$\Bbb Q[x,y]/I\cong\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+(x-1)^2-2x).$$ Then show that $2x^2-4x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (respectively over $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, to prove that $x^2+y^2-2x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ it is sufficient to say that is the equation of a circle?

Comment: I guess not. But you have many tools to show this.

Comment: I can use Eisenstein criterion, since $x$ is a prime element for which $x^2$ not divide $x^2-2x$?

Comment: Of course you can. This is one of the many tools I was referred to.